# Decay Octomap in MoveIt?

Tags: moveit, octomap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,

Is there a way to automatically "decay" the octomap somehow in MoveIt? I have the problem that sometimes obstacles don't get deleted, because the obstacle moved towards the sensor, casting a shadow on the previously occupied space and therefore preventing it from realizing the space is now free.

If any information older than x in the octomap would get deleted, this problem could be prevented. Is there already an option implemented to do this? Or am I on the wrong path and there is another solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance,

Rabe

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/183150/decay-octomap-in-moveit?/) by [Rabe](https://answers.ros.org/users/15571/rabe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 683 on 2014-07-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is an OcTreeStamped class in OctoMap that can be used for this purpose (but you will have to implement it). In fact, the decaying was implemented just like that in the [collider package](http://wiki.ros.org/collider) (by now superseded by MoveIt and octomap_server).

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2014-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rabe](https://answers.ros.org/users/15571/rabe/) on 2014-07-04**:
Hey Armin, thanks for the fast reply. Do you by chance have an overview of how MoveIt uses the Octomap? I'd be grateful if you could point in the direction of where I would  have to start to implement it (e.g. Do I have to write my own octomap-server, or just change some lines in a class in MoveIt?)